# Python: Recursively extract comment tree from nested dicts and lists

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to excract a series of comments from a data structure composed of nested dictionaries and lists. Bellow is an example of what I am dealing with and what i have written so far:

```
example = {"text" : "Level 0", 
                "children" : [{"text": "Level 1",
                                "children" : [{"text": "Level 2a"}, 
                                              {"text": "Level 2b"}]}] }


def parse_comments(comment_tree): 

    if isinstance(comment_tree, list): 
        for tree in comment_tree: 
            return parse_comments(tree)
    if isinstance(comment_tree, dict): 
        if "children" in comment_tree.keys(): 
            return comment_tree["text"], parse_comments(comment_tree["children"])
        else: 
            return comment_tree["text"]
```

Ideally, the output would look similar to this:

`[["Level 0", "Level 1", "Level 2a"], ["Level 0", "Level 1", "Level 2b"]]`

I am currently getting this:

`('Level 0', ('Level 1', 'Level 2a'))`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
example = {"text" : "Level 0", "children" : [{"text": "Level 1","children" : [{"text": "Level 2a"}, {"text": "Level 2b"}]}] }
def get_comments(d, c = []):
  if 'children' not in d:
      yield c+[d['text']]
  else:
      for i in d['children']:
         yield from get_comments(i, c+[d['text']])

print(list(get_comments(example)))
```

Output:

```
[['Level 0', 'Level 1', 'Level 2a'], ['Level 0', 'Level 1', 'Level 2b']]
```

Comment: Beware of the mutable default argument, however.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Good point, although it should not be issue in this case, as no values are being appended to it.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply.

Comment: True, not by the function itself in any case. It should not be recommended to beginners w/o disclaimer though.